# Animation with multiple marquee-tags

Tags: html, css

When there are multiple marquee-tags the behaviour in Chrome vs. Firefox and Safari is very different. Regarding the behaviour in IE/Edge I have no idea, as of now.

Is it possible, somehow, to get the same behaviour in Firefox and Safari as Chrome with the smoothish scrolling? Btw. in Chrome the animation gets faster with each marquee-tag.

```html
<marquee>
  <marquee>ASDF</marquee>
</marquee>
```

Comment: `marquee` is an **obsolete element** and shoudl no longer be used.

Comment: I know, but I'm using it in a very small chat room, and it seems to still work in all browsers as of now. But eventually I have to find some kind of replacement.

Comment: The [css] tag in your question suggests you do at least intend to replicate the behavior you're looking for in CSS, is that correct?

Comment: If it's possible with CSS, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Before I begin: `<marquee>` is **obsolete**, and for that reason should not be included in any new HTML. From the [Mozilla developer page regarding `<marquee>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) (emphasis mine):

> This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since **it could be removed at any time**. Try to avoid using it.

---

If you really, *really*, **really** ***must*** use `<marquee>`, you can assign it the `scrollamount` attribute, which seems to be supported in all major browsers ([source](http://help.dottoro.com/lhtvirxr.php)):

```html
<marquee scrollamount=1>Test - scrollamount = 1</marquee>
<marquee scrollamount=5>Test - scrollamount = 5</marquee>
<marquee scrollamount=10>Test - scrollamount = 10</marquee>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The scrollamount-property does not help me much. I'd like to get the nested <marquee>-tags to get the same behaviour in Firefox and Safari as in Chrome; the users are posting "bbcodes" with nested tags in them.

Answer (score 0):

Now as you know `marquee` is an obsolete element and you should not use it..
Here is an alternate.

```css
.marquee {
    width: 500px;
line-height: 30px;
 background-color: white;
 color: Black;
  border:1px solid gray;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.marquee1 p{  
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    animation: marquee 60s linear infinite;
}
.marquee2 p{  
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    animation: marquee 20s linear infinite;
}
.marquee3 p{  
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee marquee1">
<p>
Hi I am Marquee 1 at 60s
</p>
</div>

<div class="marquee marquee2">
<p>
Hi I am Marquee 2 at 20s
</p>
</div>

<div class="marquee marquee3">
<p>
Hi I am Marquee 3 at 10s
</p>
</div>
```

You can also test it here https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/fh1xbrz7/5/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll replace the marquee-tags with CSS.

Comment: Perfect. Glad I helped you!